# Impossible to restore Copay wallet on new phone

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, copay

I just changed my phone and reinstalled Copay.
I'm trying to restore my BTC Wallet from the 12 words key phrase i saved, but copay keeps telling me "impossible to import.Wallet Recovery sentence is invalid".

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

**Anyone has an idea?**

Use a spelling checker on your twelve-word recovery phrase.

Even better, use a tool to check the phrase against the appropriate [BIP39 dictionary](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) for your language.

---

Example

```
>wordcheck able moose zoo
able                           - OK
moose                          - Not in bip39 dictionary
zoo                            - OK
```

Source: https://github.com/redgrittybrick/wordcheck

Compiler: https://golang.org/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reaching out. You can import or restore your Bitcoin or Bitcoin Cash wallet to your device by using the 12 word backup phrase for your wallet.

Please see the following article for steps on restoring your wallet using the recovery phrase: https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003004363-I-lost-my-wallet-or-changed-my-phone-What-can-I-do-to-restore-my-wallet-

If you are experiencing an issue, here are some things that you can check:

- Are you sure that the recovery phrase was written in the correct order?
- Did you use all lowercase letters and no punctuation?
- Did you add a password to your recovery phrase?
- [Do you have the QR code or text/file backup?]

(https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003004363-I-lost-my-wallet-or-changed-my-phone-What-can-I-do-to-restore-my-wallet-)
- Did you separate each word with a single space (no commas or any other punctuation)?

Please also ensure that your words are all contained in the following list of possible words:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt